# Where to get Swagger's Bootstrap servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, swagger

I am following this [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#using-a-servlet) which gives the following example:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SwaggerBootstrap</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.api.util.Bootstrap</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

However, I cannot find where I get the `io.swagger.api.util.Bootstrap` class.

I cannot see this in the Swagger GitHub repository, and cannot find any Maven modules with this.

Where do I find this?

Comment: DuckDuckGo - first hit by searching the class name: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5   - please delete this question... it's just in the paragraph before the one you mentioned... in the page you linked.

Comment: @Magick There's no such class in Maven repositories. You have to [create it](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#using-a-servlet).

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin - ah! Doh! Thank you! I got confused with the name in the example, thinking it was in the utils package of Swagger. Ok, this make sense. Thank you!

Comment: Check this out [Swagger Sample App](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/master/java/java-jersey-jaxrs), you can get `Bootstrap.java`
Do not forget to include serial id to that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `io.swagger.api.util.Bootstrap` is only a **sample servlet**. You have to create a servlet like that in your application to [create a `BeanConfig`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#using-swaggers-beanconfig) and set up Swagger.

The servlet class name (`Bootstrap`) and the package (`io.swagger.api.util`) are only examples. Give the class the name you want and place it in the package you want.

---

From the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#using-a-servlet):

> ### Using a Servlet
>
> A sample servlet would be:
>
> ```java
> package io.swagger.api.util;
>
> import javax.servlet.ServletConfig; 
> import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
> import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
>
> public class Bootstrap extends HttpServlet {
>
>     @Override
>     public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
>         super.init(config);
>
>         BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
>         beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
>         beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
>         beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8002");
>         beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
>         beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources");
>         beanConfig.setScan(true);
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> And adding the following snippet to the web.xml will ensure the initialization of Swagger:
>
> ```xml
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>SwaggerBootstrap</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>io.swagger.api.util.Bootstrap</servlet-class>
>     <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> ```
>
> There's no need for a URL mapping for this servlet as it is only used to initialize the application.
>
> You are done with this guide! You should now be able to access the Swagger definition at `/swagger.json` and `/swagger.yaml` at the context root of your application.

Comment: The documentation is clear - but apparently my question is not. Where do I get io.swagger.api.util.Bootstrap. It is not in the maven dependency listed in the documentation.

Comment: @Magick You **won't find** this class in any Maven repositories. You **will write** this class. The package and the name of the servlet class does't matter.